# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.addEmployee

Tags: angular

My code was working fine but when i clicked on delete button only in the data table it was deleting when i refresh the page the data was appearing again , So i cleared the LocalStorage in the chrome console.

Now i'm not able to add the data to my data table from my Homepage to content page.

Getting the error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null     at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.addEmployee

this is my HomeComponent .ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  name:string;
  DOB:number;
  mob:number;
  gender:string;
  title = 'Employee Information';

  // employees = [];

  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";
  addEmployee(){
    //console.log("This.model", this.model);
    let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emp'));
    employees.push(this.model);
    localStorage.setItem('emp', JSON.stringify(employees));

   //console.log(this.employees);
    console.log(this.model);
    this.model = {};
   this.msg = "Record is successfully added..... "; 
  }
  ngOnInit(){}
}
```

this is my content.component.ts

```
export class ContentsComponent implements OnInit {
  employees = [];
     //{name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"},
    // {name:"Alex",DOB:"23-03-1995",mob:"4558965214",gender:"female"},
    // {name:"Maria",DOB:"24-02-1994",mob:"9558965214",gender:"male"}
  //];

  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  msg:any="";

  constructor(private router:Router,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,private ServersService: ServersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emp'));
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', this.employees);    
  }


  deleteEmployee(i){
    this.employees.splice(i,1);
    this.msg = "Record is successfully deleted..... ";           
  }

  myValue;
  editEmployee(k){
    this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;
    this.model2.DOB=this.employees[k].DOB;
    this.model2.mob = this.employees[k].mob;
    this.model2.gender=this.employees[k].gender;
    // console.log(this.model.gender);
    this.myValue = k;

  }
  updateEmployee(){
    let k= this.myValue;
    this.model.gender = "female";
    for(let i=0; i<this.employees.length;i++){
      if(i==k){
        this.employees[i]= this.model2;
        this.model2 = {};       
        this.msg = "Record is successfully updated..... ";
      }
    }
  }
  clickMe(){
    this.msg = "";
  }

}
```

Comment: try to `let employees = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emp'));console.log(employees);` it might be occurring because it is not returning value from localstorage since you have cleared cache

Comment: you have not declared `employee` in  your home.component.ts

Comment: When i initialized the array in the content.component.ts like   employees = [{name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"}]; still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: how to set the local storage in the chrome by pressing Clt+F12

Answer (score 0):

Initalize the array employees,

```
employees = [];
```

and then use,

```
this.employees.push(this.model);
```

Comment: When i initialized the array in the content.component.ts like **employees = [{name:"Sikandar",DOB:"22-02-1996",mob:"4558965214",gender:"male"}];** still i'm getting the same error.